# What is the best way to partially copy a JS object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2016

I'm working on a NodeJS project (using `@babel/preset-env`) and need to figure something out:

If I have two objects, one of them identical to the other but possibly minus some fields (depends on input object), how do I edit the "larger" one such that its fields are changed to the values of the matching ones from the smaller object?

That's probably worded badly, so here's an example...say I have these two objects:

```js
const obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
}

const obj2 {
    b: 'hello',
    d: 'world'
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is modify `obj1` in this instance such that the values of `obj1.b` and `obj1.d` get updated with the values from `obj2`.

Is there a way to edit the values directly, or should I just create a copy of `obj1` and set values depending on whether or not they exist in `obj2`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can use spread operator.

```
obj1 = {...obj1, ...obj2}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I forgot that spread operators even existed, I rarely use them!   Thank you very much for such a quick response!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy the properties from `obj2` over to `obj1` in place (without creating a new object and replacing any matching properties that would have already existed on obj1), you can do this:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
    obj1[key] = value;
}
```

Or, even just:

```
Object.assign(obj1, obj2)
```